# Can't see from CPanel images I uploaded from Joomla Media

Tags: joomla, cpanel

I really don't know what could be the issue but I Can't find from CPanel images I just uploaded from Joomla Media.

I created a Folder and uploaded ninety images but can't find them (folder + images) in CPanel.

I searched for about 2 hours without solution.

I also checked "Show Hidden Files (dotfiles)" in CPanel Setting but still can't see the file.

Comment: When you say cPanel, do you mean the File Manager tool in cPanel?  If so, what folder are you looking in?  The Joomla Media Manager by default will put your images in /public_html/images/   (assuming your Joomla site is in the root directory

Answer (score 0):

Using the browser, from Joomla Media (menu Contents>Media), you can right-click on a image that you can't found and choose "copy image location" or similar. So you can see where the image was stored.

Comment: Joomla Media Manager gives me this path (images/galleries/2015/ball-of-HOPE/2017).

From CPanel / File Manager, I'm able to see 'images/galleries/2015/ball-of-HOPE', but I can't find folder 2017 and all the images its contains.

I read something [here](http://joom3.zemplate.com/the-basics-of-joomla-3/understanding-media-manager) , last paragraph maybe it's due to that.

They're talking about "index.html" which needs to be copied.

I tried but still not working.

Comment: The last paragraph regarding index.html is not related with your issue. Try to use the search function in the cPanel file manager (maybe it is at the top right corner). Otherwise, download locally all images directory and look there.

Comment: How do I download locally all images directory?

Comment: You can do it by ftp. I use Filezilla.